# What is BlitCoin?

Tags: security, privacy, tools

I saw BlitCoin mentioned on [this forum thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34383.0), but didn't understand what it was.
Can someone explain what does it do?

Comment: I read the entire thread that you linked and said good, then immediately setup tor as per this article: [Setting Up A TOR Hidden Service For Bitcoin Core](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Setting_up_a_Tor_hidden_service)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dan Kaminsky has the idea that if you have enough bitcoin nodes/connections under your control, than by looking at how transaction spread across the bitcoin p2p network, you can determine ip address of a node that was the source of transaction, Blitcoin is suppose to be to the tool for that. I think that won't become a problem because use of a simple proxy that hides ip address of a sender, will be sufficient solution.

Post on forum from Dan Kaminsky himself [BitCoin Deanonymization](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34458.0)

Disscusion among developers [Blitcoin? (Black Hat 2011)](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAJNQ0stJeFx0X%2bvHZfx-3SHt3=0JAho_kqDU44mZM613YuUaSA@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=bitcoin-development)

Comment: If that's what it does, it's kind of silly. All someone has to do is create a web page that allows you to submit a transaction and the page posts it to the network. That's very easy to do, and that will completely obscure the origin of the transaction from the Bitcoin network.

Comment: @David Schwartz: A single website that hides your IP can be malcious itself or can be forced to give up your IP to say, the CIA. In that case your IP is no longer anonymous.

Comment: My point is that it renders Kaminsky's attack irrelevant. It's also very easy to hide your IP from a web site, Tor for example.

Comment: Indeed. Tor, I2P, proxies and readily-available VPN services can all thwart this attack, so I don't really see it as a serious problem. Still it's good to know what's out there.